# Remove IPv6 address from interface

Tags: networking, windows-10, ipv6, netsh, network-interface

How can I remove redundant addresses from network interface. I have a bunch of unnecessary ones, temporary and usual ones

[image]

I do it like this

```
netsh interface ipv6 delete address interface="Wi-Fi" address="2806:10ae:7:1c7b::6"
```

but get

> The system cannot find the file specified.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: output of `netsh interface ipv6 show address level=verbose`

```
Address ::1 Parameters
---------------------------------------------------------
Interface Luid     : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
Scope Id           : 0.0
Valid Lifetime     : infinite
Preferred Lifetime : infinite
DAD State          : Preferred
Address Type       : Other
Skip as Source     : false

Address fe80::306f:9747:4ce8:213b%4 Parameters
---------------------------------------------------------
Interface Luid     : Bluetooth Network Connection
Scope Id           : 0.4
Valid Lifetime     : infinite
Preferred Lifetime : infinite
DAD State          : Deprecated
Address Type       : Other
Skip as Source     : false

Address fe80::905e:9316:2889:8ee0%6 Parameters
---------------------------------------------------------
Interface Luid     : Local Area Connection* 10
Scope Id           : 0.6
Valid Lifetime     : infinite
Preferred Lifetime : infinite
DAD State          : Deprecated
Address Type       : Other
Skip as Source     : false

Address fe80::f853:8095:aa9d:d452%20 Parameters
---------------------------------------------------------
Interface Luid     : Ethernet
Scope Id           : 0.20
Valid Lifetime     : infinite
Preferred Lifetime : infinite
DAD State          : Deprecated
Address Type       : Other
Skip as Source     : false

Address fe80::7cd5:d933:51a0:d756%23 Parameters
---------------------------------------------------------
Interface Luid     : Local Area Connection* 11
Scope Id           : 0.23
Valid Lifetime     : infinite
Preferred Lifetime : infinite
DAD State          : Deprecated
Address Type       : Other
Skip as Source     : false

Address fe80::4856:331e:461b:2feb%39 Parameters
---------------------------------------------------------
Interface Luid     : vEthernet (Hyper-WiFi)
Scope Id           : 0.39
Valid Lifetime     : infinite
Preferred Lifetime : infinite
DAD State          : Preferred
Address Type       : Other
Skip as Source     : false

Address fe80::8008:fdf8:b397:c832%19 Parameters
---------------------------------------------------------
Interface Luid     : PdaNet Broadband Connection
Scope Id           : 0.19
Valid Lifetime     : infinite
Preferred Lifetime : infinite
DAD State          : Deprecated
Address Type       : Other
Skip as Source     : false
```

There is no Wi-Fi interface among them. Why?

Comment: Can you show `netsh interface ipv6 show address level=verbose`?

Comment: If you're not using IPv6, you could always just disable it on the NIC.

Comment: @grawity, added update

Comment: @spikey_richie, I aware of it, but I'm interested to do more research

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you ran this on the same computer? I just tested on a Windows 10 machine, and both `netsh int ipv6 show interface` and `netsh int ipv6 show address` report the Wi-Fi adapter – with all its addresses.

Comment: `are you sure you ran this on the same computer?` exactly. `netsh int ipv6 show interface` doesn't show Wi-Fi neither, but it definitely exists on my system, I am surfing through it just now

Comment: NB: There is usually no need to do this. IPv6 addresses are managed automatically and it is normal to have several of them at any time.